# How can I fix object trajectories in my game?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

I am making an iPhone game with a joystick. It has a ship that should fire bullets in the joystick trajectory, but for some reason I can't get the bullets to move in the proper direction. Can someone help me figure out what I might be doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
-(void) shootBulletFromShip:(Ship*)ship
{
    double degrees = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"lol"] doubleValue];    
    NSLog(@"%f",degrees);

    float fDegrees = degrees;

    velocity = CGPointMake(1, fDegrees);


    outsideScreen = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].width;

    self.position = CGPointMake(ship.position.x,ship.position.y);
    self.visible = YES;

    [self scheduleUpdate];
}
```

Comment: I want my ship to fire in the joystick trajectory. It doesnt work

Comment: You should use variable names that describe what they represent. For example, you should probably change the name of `wtf` to something like `joystickDegrees`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are setting the velocity of your bullet incorrectly in the following line.

```
velocity = CGPointMake(1, spread);
```

If `spread` indicates an angle you should probably pass the sine and cosine of that angle as the x- and y-components of your `CGPoint`, as follows.

```
velocity = CGPointMake(cos(spread), sin(spread));
```

You may need to modify this slightly, depending on whether your angle is expressed in radians or degrees.

Comment: well , it doesnt work but i think its the joystick.degrees the problem maybe i need to do something with it before.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Calculate the angle of the touch from the center of the joypad
float dx = (float)joypadBG.position.x - (float)convertedPoint.x;
float dy = (float)joypadBG.position.y - (float)convertedPoint.y;

float distance = sqrtf((joypadBG.position.x - convertedPoint.x) * (joypadBG.position.x - convertedPoint.x) + (joypadBG.position.y - convertedPoint.y) * (joypadBG.position.y - convertedPoint.y));

// Calculate the angle of the players touch from the center of the joypad
float touchAngle = atan2(dy, dx);

// If the players finger is outside of the joypad, make sure the joypad cap is drawn at the // joypad edge.
if (distance > joypadMaxRadius) 
{
    [joystick setPosition:ccp(joypadBG.position.x - cosf(touchAngle) * joypadMaxRadius, joypadBG.position.y - sinf(touchAngle) * joypadMaxRadius)];
} 
else 
{
    [joystick setPosition:convertedPoint];
}

diff = ccpSub([joystick position], joypadBG.position);
float angleRadians = atanf((float)diff.y / (float)diff.x);

float angleOffset = CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90);

if(diff.x < 0)
{
    angleRadians += angleOffset;
}
else
{
    angleRadians -= angleOffset;
}
```